# How can I reactivate the fn + arrow buttons that changed in Safari 5.1?

Tags: macos, safari, keyboard

Safari 5.1 (Snow Leopard) seems to have disabled the combination of <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> buttons for navigation (page up, page down, top, bottom). I know the same can be achieved with <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>top</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd> and <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>top</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, respectively but I find it rather impractical to use.

Are there any tips already how to reactivate this or do I even have to fear that <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> behaviour has been completely dropped in Lion?

**Edit**: Added Lion explicitly to the tags since they seemed to have dropped the *Home* and *End* behaviour of <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>arrow</kbd> there as well in many applications.

Comment: I had never used this before, so I went to test it - it's working for me on 10.7 with Safari 5.1. Maybe a bug/some sort of conflict with something else that happened during the upgrade?

Comment: Hmm, no idea. I have made some special keybindings before for something similar – but this has never been a problem for any application ever. Going to check this soon. On the other hand, it is amazing how quickly I got used to using option and command for this already…

Comment: Let me know how it works out. I have some custom keybinds set up for Safari, but this is working.  Possibly relevant - what kind of keyboard are you using? Wired, wireless, laptop's built in? I'm on the full-sized aluminum, no issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that home/end/pgup/pgdown aren't working on my main user account but if I create a new user and log in as them, they all work as expected.  So I figure it's a snipe hunt for some preference/library/plugin manager that is doing horrible things to Safari.  I already purged SIMBL but it doesn't look like it helped.

(edited to add) I poked around some more and I guess I made some changes to my default key bindings at some point - I removed ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict and now PgUp/PgDown/Home/End all work as I expect in a browser, although now I'm stuck with emacs navigation inside of editboxes.  I can manage.

Comment: I had the same problem. I had remapped ⇞ and ⇟ to `pageUp:` and `pageDown:` (which move the caret in addition to scrolling the page, unlike the default `scrollPageUp:` and `scrollPageDown:`). But those methods stopped working in Safari 5.1 and some version of Chrome released around the same time. You wouldn't have needed to remove DefaultKeyBinding.dict completely.